# function that returns values after an index of an array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

what i thought was going to be simple just has me stumped i guess, im trying to return everything in the array after the index, please help! here is what i have, its suppose create a new array by console log

```
function loops(param1,param2){
  let num = param2;
  let newArray = [];
  for( let i = num; i < param1.length; i++){
      newArray.push(param1[i])
    }
    return loops;
    //newconcate new array then console log
  }
console.log(loops(['1','2','3','4','hi','there'], 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning loops from the method you should return newArray like this,

```js
function loops(param1,param2){
  let num = param2;
  let newArray = [];
  for( let i = num; i < param1.length; i++){
      newArray.push(param1[i])
    }
    return newArray;
    //newconcate new array then console log
  }
console.log(loops(['1','2','3','4','hi','there'], 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `return` you are returning the function it self not your `newArray`

Comment: wow.. thanks so much i cant believe i let that slide

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to return everything *after* the index, i.e. you're returning ['hi','there'] from your example array you need **let i = num+1** or **let num = param2 + 1** as well as **returning newArray** instead of the function:

```
function loops(param1,param2){
  let num = param2;
  let newArray = [];
  for( let i = num+1; i < param1.length; i++){
      newArray.push(param1[i])
    }
    return newArray;
  }
console.log(loops(['1','2','3','4','hi','there'], 3));
```